# Div Not Center Using class="center-block" in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying make a hanoi tower.

I want to put the control part be centre as , so I checked Bootstrap and using `class="center-block"`, but nothing work, like this: [image: no centre]
<sub>(source: [wuzhiwei.net](http://wuzhiwei.net/problems/no-center.png))</sub>

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/timwzw/S7mYF/12).

#### Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Hanoi Tower</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <canvas id="stage" class="center-block" width="400" height="220" style="border:1px black solid "></canvas>
            <div id="ctrl" class="center-block">
                <label for="numsel">Disc Number：</label>
                <select id="numsel">
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="start" value="start">Start</button>
                <label for="step">Step：</label> <span class="badge" id="step">0</span>  

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.panel {
    min-width:400px;
}
#stage {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#start {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

### Quesition

How can I make this div `<div id="ctrl" class="center-block">` be centred?

Comment: your block not align using the class "center-block" because you not define a width to your `<div class="ctrl">` put a width and this class will work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7mYF/13/)

You need to add the class `text-center` to the `div` with the `id` `panel-body`.

Change your HTML to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Hanoi Tower</div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <canvas id="stage" class="center-block" width="400" height="220" style="border:1px black solid "></canvas>
            <div id="ctrl" class="center-block">
                <label for="numsel">Disc Number：</label>
                <select id="numsel">
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="start" value="start">Start</button>
                <label for="step">Step：</label> <span class="badge" id="step">0</span>  

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or [change your CSS to add](http://jsfiddle.net/S7mYF/14/):

```
.panel-body{
  text-align:center;
}
```

All the class `center-block` does is to tell the element to have a margin of `0 auto`, the `auto` being the left/right margins. However, unless the class `text-center` or css `text-align:center;` is set on the parent, the element does not know the point to work out this `auto` calculation from so will not center itself as anticipated.

Comment: Wow nice work, but what did you change in HTML? I see is `text-center`?

Comment: See the part: `<div class="panel-body text-center">` the class `text-center` was added, this is a bootstrap centering class

Answer (score 3):

Add this class in your css

```
.center-block{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S7mYF/16/)

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a fixed with (say 400px) and margin: 0 auto;

```
.center-block{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S7mYF/19/)

Or you can just use text-align: center;

```
.center-block{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/S7mYF/20/)

Comment: your answer are right, but, not recommend modify a bootstrap class, because it may need reuse this same class in other block of code

Comment: Yeah, You can either use #ctrl for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align:center` to the div `.center-block`

Comment: This is not necessary, as Bootstrap has a built in centering class `text-center` that can be used, as @SW4 mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Chad you are absolutely right. I just gave a quick css solution. :)

Answer (score -1):

add this class in your css

```
.center-block{
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

good luck!